# Software Requirements Specification - Functional Requirements

Tags: requirements, software-design

I'm preparing an SRS document for a new software and I'm facing difficulty in distinguishing between the "Functional Requirements Definition" and "Detailed Functional Requirements".

The former, I am using "Use Cases" to briefly introduce the user on the functionality. The latter, a tabular form should be used specifying "Precondition, Trigger, Basic Path, etc ...".

Are both sections the same? Some recommend using State Chart, shall I conclude the State Chart from the Use Case definition?

Any worth guidance is appreciated.

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are as many SRS templates as there are software architects so it's a little hard to give a good answer, but I think you're on the right track with an overview (perhaps in use case form) in the Definition section and more details in the Detailed section.

When it comes to elaborating use cases, I usually steer clear of state charts. I feel they're better suited for describing design rather than specifying functionality. I like Activity diagrams for this purpose, but again it depends on the type of system you are specifying.